# Cookies location of Vivaldi

Tags: windows-10, chromium, cookies, vivaldi

I was trying to view my cookies but I can't really find them?
Sure, you can see them inside the browser but you can't really do anything with them that way aside from viewing them.

Does anyone know where their physical location is on windows10? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked the Vivaldi community!

https://forum.vivaldi.net/topic/42442/physical-location-of-cookies-on-windows-10/2

You can find it in here: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Vivaldi\User Data\Default`